# Go pass dynamic parameter to a function

Tags: go

I’ve a function which should do something like this

```
func getA(m *m.TSR, bl string) string {
    runParams, exist := m.BuildParams.Before[bl]
    if exist {
        runParamsMap, ok := runParams.(map[interface{}]interface{})
        if ok {
            run, ok := runParamsMap["builder"]
            if ok {
                return run.(string)
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}


func getB(m *m.TSR, bl string) string {
    runParams, exist := m.BuildParams.After[bl]
    if exist {
        runParamsMap, ok := runParams.(map[interface{}]interface{})
        if ok {
            run, ok := runParamsMap["builder"]
            if ok {
                return run.(string)
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Both function are **working as expected** , but I wonder if there is a way to use just only **one function** that handle the same ?
The only difference is the Before & After

```
m.BuildParams.Before[bl]

m.BuildParams.After[bl]
```

All the reset is exactly the same, any idea how to combine them **without** removing the those line outside the function ….

maybe with additional parameter ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to move the common part to another function, e.g. `get()`, and change `getA()` and `getB()` to call this `get()`:

```
func getB(m *m.TSR, bl string) string {
    runParams, exist := m.BuildParams.Before[bl]
    return get(runParams, exist)
}

func getB(m *m.TSR, bl string) string {
    runParams, exist := m.BuildParams.After[bl]
    return get(runParams, exist)
}

func get(runParams interface{}, exists bool) string {
    if exist {
        runParamsMap, ok := runParams.(map[interface{}]interface{})
        if ok {
            run, ok := runParamsMap["builder"]
            if ok {
                return run.(string)
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

If `m.BuildParams.Before` and `m.BuildParams.After` are of the same type (be it `commonType`), you can do better:

```
func getA(m *m.TSR, bl string) string {
    return get(m.BuildParams.Before, bl)
}

func getB(m *m.TSR, bl string) string {
    return get(m.BuildParams.After, bl)
}
```

And only the first line changes in `get()`:

```
func get(common commonType, bl string) string {
    runParams, exist := common[bl]
    // rest is same
}
```